# Splitting ethernet port

Tags: ethernet, internet

Splitting ethernet port

We recently changed a living room into a bedroom. However, there's no ethernet port in the space.

We have an ethernet port on the other side of an adjacent wall.

**I know ethernet port splitting isn't advisable and will result in reduces speeds ≈ 100mbps**

I'm looking for a switch that can be mounted inside the wall from which I can run 2 Ethernet ports.

Also, I prefer if the switch can be powered over PoE.

Does something like that exist? Or am I looking for a unicorn?

Comment: They *do* exist, but seem to be really uncommon. Searching for "in wall POE 2 ethernet" finds a few options like https://www.cyberdata.net/products/011528v and https://www.amazon.com/PoE-Texas-GBT-4-IW-Gigabit-Extender/dp/B07Z59SG17?th=1 but you still would need to pull a cable between sides of the wall.

Comment: What is the ethernet port on the other side of the wall used for?

Comment: 100mbps isnt a bad speed, what are you using it for ?

Answer (score 9):

Skip the "inside the wall" part and you're in the realm of *sure, that's available.* (note that some products may be *called or named* "in-wall" while *actually* mounting on a junction box on the face of the wall.)

2-3 port POE switches (with WiFi built in in many cases) are available that mount to an outlet box. Then you just need a cable from the other room into the outlet box in the room with service. Since you can get such switches with two of the ports "on the back" inside the box, it can be done cleanly. While 8 port POE switches are also available, most don't do the back access trick.

If you're going to insist on burying the POE switch in the wall, please have the common sense to do so with an access panel, not **[The Cask of Amontillado](https://poestories.com/read/amontillado)** style.

Comment: "For the love of god, Montresor!" I personally feel like the 'doing it right' option would be - if you're going to cut an access port, or pull a wire from another room - it might make sense to just pull a cable to somewhere with proper access

Comment: Meh. The typical home use scenario is highly unlikely to notice going from a port to a switch to a switch to a router to the internet *.vs.* going from a port to a switch to a router to the internet.

Answer (score 4):

PoE-powered switches aren't common, but they do exist.  You may only have limited remaining power if you then want to forward the power to PoE devices connected to the switch.

The loss of speed will be negligible unless both devices connected to the ethernet switch want to comminicate at high speed at the same time.

The bandwidth isn't shared so that each device gets half.  Ethernet works on the basis that if a device wants to transmit a data packet, it checks that the line is quiet and then transmits.  So one device with a lot of data to send can do so, provided the other device isn't sending lots of data too.

It's also worth bearing in mind that 100Mbps Ethernet is a bit obsolete now.  Most devices made in the last few years will work at 1Gbps.  So two devices that both need to communicate at 100Mbps won't have any problem if you use 1Gbps Ethernet routers and switches.

Comment: The OP is desiring to use a gigabit switch and 4 pairs per port *rather* than be limited to 100 MB (by using only two pairs per port on one cable.)

Answer (score 4):

Ubiquiti has the [U6 In-Wall Access point](https://eu.store.ui.com/eu/en/collections/unifi-wifi-inwall-compact) which can be mounted **in** the wall which means on top of an existing outlet with the box actually hanging on the wall.
Its a bit pricey and does way more than you need but it is powered via PoE and comes from a reputable brand.

If cost is the main driver then go with a regular 5 port switch from tp-link or netgear. These need a wall outlet but you can usually find them in any electronics store for like 20$/€.

I would definitely avoid any splitter or Y-cable. These are not worth the hassle. An alternative is powerline which can also be quite finicky (latency, timeouts etc.) but they also don't require much cabling if you can manage to plug both adapter into the same phase.